# Installing eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I need to install eclipse plugin required by [Test and Performance Tools Platform (TPTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/?ver=4.7.2#requirements).

When I downloaded EMF Runtime, I have two directories: one is feature and the other one is plugins.

[image]

Then, what is the next step for installing them into eclipse?

My eclipse installation has directories including features/plugins and dropins. Is the plugin installation is just copying the files into feature/plugins directories and restart the eclipse? Or do I need any other step for the installation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just copy and restart eclipse. if you get problems with eclipse, then start on command line with "`eclipse -clean"`